# SQLAlchemy one-to-many relationship between subclasses

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, subclass, many-to-one

I have a problem defining a one-to-many relationship between two subclasses in SQLAlchemy. I have a base class called `CompanyModel`. From it I inherit two classes: `BusinessUnitModel` and `ClientModel`. I need to create a column in `BusinessUnitModel` called `clients` containing a list of `ClientModels` and one in `ClientModel` containing the corresponding `BusinessUnitModel` i.e. create a one-to-many relationship

So far, the code I have written is similar to the following:

```
class CompanyModel(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "companies"
company_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
type = db.Column(db.Enum(CompanyType))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": type,
        "polymorphic_identity": CompanyType.COMPANY,
    }
    
    def __init__():
        ...

class BusinessUnitModel(CompanyModel):
__tablename__ = "business_units"
id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("companies.company_id"), primary_key=True)

    # one-to-many
    client_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("clients.id"))
    clients = db.relationship(
        "ClientModel", back_populates="business_unit", foreign_keys="ClientModel.id"
    )
    
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": CompanyType.BUSINESS_UNIT,
    }
    
    def __init__(...):
        ...

class ClientModel(CompanyModel):
__tablename__ = "clients"
id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("companies.company_id"), primary_key=True)

    # many-to-one
    business_unit_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("business_units.id"))
    business_unit = db.relationship(
        "BusinessUnitModel", back_populates="clients", foreign_keys=business_unit_id
    )
    
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": CompanyType.CLIENT,
    }
    
    def __init__(...):
        ...`
```

This configuration creates the correct tables in the database, but when I try to update `BusinessUnitModel` by adding a client to its client list, it happens that the client id in the database is overwritten with that of the business unit. Below are some screenshots to better clarify the situation:

- Before the update:

  [CompanyModle table before the update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wPRy.png)

  [ClientModle table before the update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBofY.png)

  [BusinessUnitModle table before the update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMKxO.png)
- After the update:

  [ClientModle table after the update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFICW.png)

How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much to anyone who can help me!

Comment: If both tables have foreign keys to each other that is not one-to-many, that is many-to-many. A BusinessUnit could have many clients. A client could have many BusinessUnits.

Comment: The problem is that without foreign keys on both sides (i.e. following the usual one-to-many pattern between two tables without any relationship) SQLAlchemy generates an AmbiguousForeignKeysError. And this makes sense, because it cannot figure out how to connect the two tables due to the fact that they both inherit from a base table.